# Using packer to create a vagrant qemu/kvm box

Tags: vagrant, qemu, kvm, packer

I am attempting to build a vagrant `.box` using the qemu/kvm hypervisor using packer. I am using the vagrant plugin `vagrant-libvirt`.

In my packer `base.json` file, I am using the vagrant post-processor, like

```
"post-processors": [
    {
        "type": "vagrant",
        "output": "output/my-ubuntu_14.04_packer.box"
    }
],
```

When I build the box however, I get this error in the logs:

```
2015/12/22 20:11:57 ui error: Build 'qemu' errored: 1 error(s) occurred:
* Post-processor failed: Unknown artifact type, can't build box: transcend.qemu
```

I've looked in to this issue, and it does seem to be caused by that post-processor configuration. For example, according to the conversation [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/1208), qemu did not support the vagrant post processor at that time. However, looking at this it should work now that [this pull request](https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/pull/1330) is merged.

In fact, the [documentation](http://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/vagrant.html) for the vagrant post-processor seems lists qemu as a supported provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because I am currently using `Packer v0.6.0` (released May 2, 2014). The vagrant post-processor wasn't supported until `Packer v0.7.2` (released Oct 28, 2014), so an upgrade would be necessary to achieve this.